# Spring Profile Groups in Spring Cloud Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to use the Profile Groups added in SpringBoot 2.4 to replace the old `spring.profile.include` that was changed in the same SB version.

To give some context, we are using Spring Cloud Config Server and with a structure similar to

```
shared
 |_ application.yml
 |_ application-dev-01.yml 
 |_ application-dev-02.yml 
 |_ application-dev.yml 
 |_ application-prod.yml 
services
 |_ myService1
      |_ myService1.yml
      |_ mySerrice1-dev.yml
      |_ mySerrice1-prod.yml
```

We have many dev environments (dev-01, dev-02) and we specify the right one when we start the service. In each environment-specific profile we specify the database urls, creds, etc.
Then we want to activate a global `dev` if running in any of the `dev-XX` environment for anything that is shared.

This seems like a perfect use case for the profile groups, something like:

```
spring:
  profiles.group:
    dev-01: dev
    dev-02: dev
```

If I put this Profile Groups config in the bundled `application.yml` of my service, it works as expected. However, if I put it in side the `application.yml` in Spring Cloud Config, it does not seem to be picked up.

Is it expected that we can only put those profile groups in the bundled files?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue about this problem in the Spring Cloud Config Github repository:

[Profile groups are not honored by client](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1876)

There is another similar open issue:

[Spring Cloud Config: Bootstrap context not loading profile-specific property files for binding](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/2005)

In the later issue, a user is recommending as a workaround to define both `spring.profiles.active` and `spring.cloud.config.profile`, but I didn't succeed in reproducing this workaround in my context.

There is also an issue about this problem in the Spring Boot Github repository:

[Using spring cloud config, Profile groups not working](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/27530)

but the issue is closed because the problem comes from the Spring Cloud Config project.